# iPhone Simulator stucks on launchscreen. Struct issues in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, struct

This is my very first time using struct in Objective-C and I can't figure it out where I'd go wrong. Let's me explain better:

In my "AppData" class I have created a struct. For instance let's suppose containing some information about market products.

```
// Struct declaration
typedef struct {
    int apple;
    int banana;
    int cherry;
} Products; 

// Variable declaration
@property (assign, nonatomic) Products products;
```

The first thing my app does on startup is to check if some keys exist inside the NSUserDefault, then update the `products` (in order to an easy access to those values). This is the way I try to achieve this step:

```
+ (void)update
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaultUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    Products updatedProducts;

    if ([defaultUser objectForKey:@"apple"] != nil)
        updatedProducts.apple = [[defaultUser objectForKey:@"apple"] intValue];

    if ([defaultUser objectForKey:@"banana"] != nil)
        updatedProducts.banana = [[defaultUser objectForKey:@"banana"] intValue];

    if ([defaultUser objectForKey:@"cherry"] != nil)
        updatedProducts.cherry = [[defaultUser objectForKey:@"cherry"] intValue];

    // Update
    [[AppData sharedData] setProducts:updatedProducts];

    // Synchronize
    [defaultUser synchronize];
}
```

The result of this is an infinite in the launch screen (The number of nodes and fps are not even loaded).
I tried also with `[AppData sharedData].products = updatedProducts;` but nothing changes.

I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't figure it out what. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Tap the 'Pause' button in Xcode once it freezes - what's the state of your main thread?

Comment: why are you calling `synchronize` on the `NSUserDefaults` if you are not updating them? (you're only reading data). Also, what does `[[AppData sharedData] setProducts:updatedProducts];` actually do? Try commenting sections out to work out where the problem is